# Cronjob using the mail function

Tags: linux, bash, cron

When I run this mail command from the terminal, there's no problems:

```
mail -s "Test Mail" user@example.com < home/user/example.txt
```

When I add it to a bash script that mainly does this, there's no problems:

```
tmpString=$(ssh user@server `perl -s` < /home/user/perlscript.pl 2> errorfile.txt)
mail -s "Test Mail" user@example.com < home/user/example.txt
```

But, when I create a crontab to run the bash script, the mail never gets sent:

```
10 14 * * * /home/user/mybashscript
```

However, I do recieve an email from cronjob about the output. The email with the subject "Test Mail" never arrives.

Anyone had this issue before?

The trace:

Ok, I'll just change some of personal related naming. The mail should be sent before the last echo, but it's not showing up in the trace?

```
+ . /home/user/.bashrc
++ PS1=`\u@\h \w$`
++ TERM=vt100
++PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
++ ssh user@example `perl -s`
+ scriptString=`$VAR` = ``\``Build was OK`\``;`
+echo `$VAR1`= ``\``Build was OK`\``;`
$VAR1 = `Build was OK`;
+ [[ $VAR1 = `Build was OK`; == *\B\u\i\l\d\ \f\a\i\l\e\d* ]]
+ echo
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are the permissions of a file? Were you able to add another cron job with another bash file that i.e simply `echo`es in a file to make sure that your cron job can be executed?

Comment: When the cron jub runs, I recieve an email from it with what i echoed, so I think it runs OK.

Answer (score 0):

`crontab` don't have the same environment as yours, so in the top of your script, after the *shebang*, put :

```
. ~/.bashrc || . /etc/profile
```

this will set PATH for child process.

Moreover, modify the `shebang` to `#!/bin/bash -x` to turn **debug ON**, and in your `crontab` do this :

```
* * * * * /path/to/script >/tmp/trace 2>&1
```

and come again with the debug trace.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried adding the line, but the mail still isn't being sent.

Comment: See my edited post after _Moreover_

Comment: Ok, I'll just change some of personal related naming. The mail should be sent before the last echo, but it's not showing up in the trace?

+ . /home/user/.bashrc
++ PS1=`\u@\h \w$`
++ TERM=vt100
++PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin ++ssh user@example `perl -s`
+ scriptString=`$VAR` = ``\``Build was OK`\``;`
+echo `$VAR1`= ``\``Build was OK`\``;`
$VAR1 = `Build was OK`;
+ [[ $VAR1 = `Build was OK`; == *\B\u\i\l\d\ \f\a\i\l\e\d* ]]
+ echo

Comment: Please, paste it in your post or on http://pastebin.com

Comment: Ok, I edited my first post

Comment: Oh my. I'm so embarrassed. I was checking for "Build failed" to send the mail, it returned "Build OK", so it was never sent. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. You can 'accept' the reply too by clicking the outline of the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackoverflow website will known that the question is well answered. That's how stackechange websites works, thanks ;)